# como puedo ejecutar mi macro cuando se abra excel

Tags: php, excel, vba, macros

que tal quiero saber si cuando abro mi hoja de excel hay forma que se ejecute una macro guardada ya que la ejecutare con un bath
entonces cuando se abra quiero que mande un correo

este es el codigo de la macro

VBA

```
Option Explicit


Sub ENVIO_MAIL_FIRMA()
'Declaramos variables
Dim objMail As Object, olApp As Object
Dim imagen As String, texto As String
Dim i As Integer, Fin As Integer

With Sheets("CORREO")
Fin = Application.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
For i = 2 To Fin
'Obtenemos logo o imagen para firma
imagen = "C:\ruta\img.png"
'Incluimos texto del correo
texto = .Cells(i, 2).Value
'Creamos objeto Outlook y componemos el mensaje
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
With objMail
.Subject = "Impresion de pantalla"
.to = "valerianoallende@cmg.mx"
'Adjuntamos la imagen o logo, la ocultamos de los archivos adjunto
.Attachments.Add imagen, 0
'componemos la firma en el campo Htmlbody, incluimos hipervínculo.
.HTMLBody = texto & "" _
& ""
.send
End With
Next i
End With
Set objMail = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

y asi se ve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que al abrirla se ejecute la macro y se cierre el excel solo

me mamnda error cuando ejecuto mi bat

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui la macro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Sí se puede. Lo primero que tienes que hacer es abrir el Editor de VBA, doble clic en el objeto `ThisWorkbook` y configuras el evento `Open`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que debes poner es:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call ENVIO_MAIL_FIRMA
End Sub
```

Luego, asegúrate que en el Centro de Confianza de Excel tienes agregado este archivo como una fuente de fiar. Excel por defecto bloquea las macros. Pero puedes configurar para que haya archivos que admita automáticamente las macros. Añade la carpeta donde esté este archivo y listo. Para ello, OPCIONES EXCEL-->CENTRO DE CONFIANZA-->CONFIGURACIÓN CENTRO CONFIANZA-->UBICACIONES DE CONFIANZA-->Marca casilla `Permitir ubicaciones que estén en la red`--> Agregar (y buscas tu carpeta)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo tengo varios procesos así, con archivos BAT, de tal manera que al llegar a la oficina a primera hora, tengo hechos algunos informes ya, y no pierdo tiempo.

Comment: ya lo hice y al ejeutar el bat me manda error ya edite la pregunta con los errores

Comment: ¿Existe una hoja que se llame CORREO? De todas formas mejor utiliza referencias completas, pon `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CORREO")`

Comment: si existe y ya le puse y me funciono pero y para por ejemplo quitar el de habilitar excel? es necesario precionar el boton

Comment: ya lo habilite gracias